# How to restore SQL Server bak files in Access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I backuped some SQL Server 2008 R2 databases using .bak files within SSMS, I sent them to a client and they're willing to open them within MS Access.

Can you please tell me if this is possible and if limitations exists to perfmrom this procedures?

My bak files are 40GB aprox

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to restore a SQL Server backup into MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access does not support that kind of action. I believe your best bet wold be to create a MS Access database and export the data from SQL Management Studio to the access database file. You can also try to export to flat file CSV and have them import it that way.